# Excel VBA: Intersect methode with several names range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The Intersect don't work.

> Dim NTit As Range
> Dim NInf As Range
> Dim NDat As Range
>
> Dim WS As Worksheet
> Set WS = ActiveSheet
>
> ```
>    Set NTit = WS.Range("$A$1:$J$1")       
>    Set NInf = WS.Range("$B$3:$F$3")       
>    Set NDat = WS.Range("$A$5:$K$11")       
>    NTit.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
>    If Not Intersect(Target, NTit, NInf, NDat) Is Nothing Then
> ```

Comment: Please take a minute to reword this question in a way to make it easier to understand what you are attempting and what your question is. It may be helpful to read ***[ask]***.

Comment: When I run Change Event,normally The intersect part must jump over the code who follow if enter data is in cell outside the ranges & execute the code if the enter data is inside the ranges but in fact jump over the code each time. I know that each Ranges are correct because I paint then it must be a error in ligne within Intersect? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Intersect` is not working because each parameter must have a common cell or cells. It is not an OR situation; it is an AND. You need to essentially use `Target AND (NTit OR NInf OR NDat)`. This can be accomplished by combining `Intersect` with `Union`.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Union(NTit, NInf, NDat)) Is Nothing Then
```

This looks like it might be from a `Worksheet_Change` event macro. If that is the case, then you do not have to declare and assign `WS`. You could just use `ME` as the worksheet object. There are other improvements I could suggest but you would edit your question and post more of your code before I could see how this relates to other factors.

Comment: This is a good answer.